# Azure ServiceBus PeekBatch method returns wrong number of records

Tags: azure, queue, servicebus, peek

I have an Azure queue (ServiceBus Topic Subscription DeadLetter queue) with ~900 messages. I would like to list them for debug purposes. I call PeekBatch method with parameter messageCount set to 100. I expect to get 100 messages but I only receive 69. Why is that???

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a similar issue recently where the reported Active Message Count number was higher than the actual number of messages that could be read.  After some investigation, I contacted Microsoft's Azure support team.  Here's what they told me:

> After researching I see that there is bug about this where the count is not showing correct value. The bug is active so it’s not resolved. Product group is tracking it but I don’t have any ETA on it.

Although in my case it's the Active Message Count that was off, this could very well be the same issue.

I found a way (that only works some of the times - I don't know why) to correct the message count.  Use Service Bus Explorer, select the topic that is displaying the issue, hit Update (without having changed any of the settings) and then hit Refresh.

Comment: Dec 2019 here and this bug is still active. Ran into it yesterday, glad I came across this.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue, when I tried to peek messages from queue which is enabled partitioning. if I use PeekBatch method with passing message count as parameter, I can read only some of the messages even the actual message count was higher than that.

Partition queue - Partitioned queue consists of multiple fragments handled by different message brokers. when a message is sent to the partitioned queue, Service Bus assigns the message to one of the fragments. When a client wants to receive a message from a queue, Service Bus checks all fragments for messages. if it finds any, it picks one and passes to the receiver.

So, When we try to get messages using PeekBatch() method, it checks the fragments for messages and picks the messages from the fragment which it found at first, even if it is not matched with the given message count.